# How can I find views per page for each section of my site via Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, page-views, google-data-studio

I have a number of sections of my site, along the lines of '*acme.org/primary*' and '*acme.org/secondar*y'.

Let's say that *'Primary'* has 40'000 page views, and *'Secondary'* has only 5'000. However - *Primary* has '20'000' pages in it, and *Secondary* has only 5 pages in it. Thus, *Secondary* has a lot more **views per page** than *Primary*, despite having far fewer page views overall.

This to me seems like an important indicator of how valuable a group of pages are — but I can't find any simple way of viewing these numbers, without manually finding the number of pages and setting the information out on a spreadsheet. I've been searching Google for a solution but have had no luck.

(For reference, I plan to chart this data in DataStudio - if there is a solution I can apply there that would work too.)

**How can I find the views per page for sections of my site via Google Analytics?**

Comment: Google Analytics is not good at giving visibility into sections of your site.   You can create filters or advanced segments for different sections, but even then you can't compare them in a single report.

Comment: I also don't know a way of counting pages in Google Analytics.   The best it can probably do is to count pages that get at least one page view.   They could be pages that GA doesn't even know about because they don't get any views.

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this article.](https://thevunderkind.com/google-analytics-how-to-see-traffic-per-page-on-your-website-4961768516a4)

> Using Content Drilldown to Find Single Page Views on Analytics:
>   Open Analytics and go to the Reporting tab on the dashboard. Scroll a little down on the navigation tab on the left and look for the selection marked ‘Behavior.’ Click on ‘Site Content’ and ‘Content Drilldown’. You are there.

Answer (score 0):

Open *Analytics Dashboard > Reports > Behavior > Site Content*

Here you have 4 sections:

**All Pages:** Information on all the pages of your site that have been viewed.

**Content Drilldown:**  The same data as in the All Pages, but it is broken down by sub folder.

**Landing Pages:** about which pages users entered the website on.

**Exit Pages:** Pages which have been the final page of a session.

More detailed information is available [here](https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2340779/google-analytics-content-reports-understanding-the-key-benefits).

Answer (score 0):

Right, after looking into this for some time I've arrived at a solution.

I've exported my data to Google Data Studio - where I've created two CASE statements. One categorises content on my site as a Dimension (Content Category), the other counts the number of pages in those pages as a metric (Number of Pages).

I created a final metric, Views per Page (Page Views/Number of Pages), which I plotted against Content Category. This gives me a dynamically updating representation of 'Views per Page' for each content type on my site.

I've written this up in much more detail on my blog for anyone who arrives on this question in the future:
http://rhysmills.com/analytics/visualising-views-per-page-in-data-studio/